# formating string to hex and validate

Tags: c++-cli

I have an application that accepts hex values from a C++/CLI `richtextbox`.
The string comes from a user input.

Sample input and expected output.

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A  //good input

0102030405060708090A           //bad input but can automatically be converted to good by adding spaces.

XX ZZ DD AA OO PP II UU HH SS  //bad input this is not hex

01 000 00 00 00 00 00 01 001 0 //bad input hex is only 2 chars
```

How to write function:
1. Detect if input is good or bad input.
2. If its a bad input check what kind of bad input: no spaces, not hex, must be 2 chars split.
3. If its no spaces bad input then just add the spaces automatically.

So far I made a space checker by searching for a space like:

```
for ( int i = 2; i < input.size(); i++ ) 
{
    if(inputpkt[i] == ' ')
    {
        cout << "good input" << endl;
        i = i+2;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "bad input. I will format for you" << endl;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't really work as expected because it returns this:

```
01 000 //bad input
01 000 00 00 00 00 00 01 001 00 //good input
```

---

*update*

1 Check if input is actually hex:

```
bool ishex(std::string const& s)
{
    return s.find_first_not_of("0123456789abcdefABCDEF ", 0) == std::string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you operating in C++/CLI, or in plain C++? You've got it tagged C++/CLI, but you're using std::string, not .Net [System::String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx).

I suggest this as a general plan: First, split your large string into smaller ones based on any whitespace. For each individual string, make sure it only contains [0-9a-fA-F], and is a multiple of two characters long.

The implementation could go something like this:

```
array<Byte>^ ConvertString(String^ input)
{
    List<System::Byte>^ output = gcnew List<System::Byte>();

    // Splitting on a null string array makes it split on all whitespace.
    array<String^>^ words = input->Split(
        (array<String^>)nullptr, 
        StringSplitOptions::RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for each(String^ word in words)
    {
        if(word->Length % 2 == 1) throw gcnew Exception("Invalid input string");

        for(int i = 0; i < word->Length; i += 2)
        {
            output->Add((Byte)(GetHexValue(word[i]) << 4 + GetHexValue(word[i+1])));
        }
    }

    return output->ToArray();
}

int GetHexValue(Char c) // Note: Upper case 'C' makes it System::Char
{
    // If not [0-9a-fA-F], throw gcnew Exception("Invalid input string");
    // If is [0-9a-fA-F], return integer between 0 and 15.
}
```